# LinearLayout cuts off TextView text by using weight property (height)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-linearlayout

I want to make a design for every android device. For this, I use LinearLayouts with height and with it a percentage solution.

The screen is divided in many sections (LinearLayouts with weights). In these LinearLayouts are the elements, like a TextView.

But if I a LinearLayout with height could cut off the TextView on the bottom side.

How can I change the text size dynamically, based on the weights?

The code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05799" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.86951">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Benachrichtigungen"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/header"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.0722106" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot and your current xml may help this to be answered faster.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thank you for your suggestion. :)

Comment: Do you need to constraint your height? If not set the outter LinearLayout height to wrap_content maybe.

Comment: This is not possible, because the outter LinearLayout is wrapped in another LinearLayout.

Comment: If so, I suggest you to wrap them by a ScrollView, that way your content is still be fine while the Overall UI can be scrolled to response to different devices.

Comment: Also, my last comment is there is new “AutoResizeTextView available from Android 8.0 (API 26) and backward supported by Support Library. It may help you as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't found a runnable version of AutoResizeTextView for Xamarin.. I think I have solved my problem on the programmable way.

Comment: It can solve by using RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my problem programmatically:

This code is in the OnCreateView method in my fragment. It generates the text size based on the height of the TextView.

```
view.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (sender, e) => 
{
    var headerTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.header);
    var headerTextViewHeightInSp = PxToSp(view.Context, headerTextView.Height);

    headerTextView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, headerTextViewHeightInSp - 5); // 5 is a offset (space between outter borderline and text)
};
```